# minify , defer and speed up the slider revolution js css files in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, google-pagespeed, litespeed, gtmetrix

I'm using the slider revolution plugin in my site
I tried to speed up my site but becuse of slider revolution the score is aroung 60 in gtmetrix
asked several times from the auhotrs and they did noting for...

I'm using Litespeed webserver and Litespeed cache plugin and it was configured
the them is astra and already was minified and have exellent speed but when the slider is avtivate , the speed is going down
All metrics of speed are fine but slider revolution croupt the others and coulden't find the good solution for.
Thanks

Comment: You might want to ask here https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/litespeed-cache/

Answer (score 1):

we have a tutorial covering the typical issues: https://www.sliderrevolution.com/tutorials/optimizing-load-speed-and-performance/

If you need more advanced help (since the litespeed plugin is not covered directly in there) one of our experts would have to take a look into your installation to understand what is going on more deeply. Please raise a ticket at https://support.sliderrevolution.com in that case, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Great thread. Worked like a charm! I spent hours of work and research looking for the files that housed the "script" tags (ie: header.php)and lost my mind till I found this thread... its a simple setting but sometimes its just about knowing where the settings are. Awsome!

Comment: Would you please share your experience with us?